# Synching remote linux system time to local windows laptop

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I run some test scripts on a remote Linux machine using my local windows laptop. Both machines are connected router and accebile to each other through Ethernet.

I am able to read the Linux system time by SSHing to the Linux system and running the date command.
I convert the returned string from such command to python datetime object.

Using such datetime object I try to set the time on the local windows host using win32api.SetSystemTime().

It all appears to work fine but the time on windows is getting updated incorrectly (hours). I guess it's got to do with timezone but I don't know how can I pass the info to wni32api.SetSystemTime() correctly to fix this.

When the time on remote Linux is 18.08 pm on windows it is being set as 11.08 am.

Here is my code:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime
import paramiko
import win32api

hostComputerTime = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print ('The host laptop current date and time is - ', hostComputerTime)

HOST = "192.168.1.2"
PORT = 22
uname = 'root'
pwd = 'mypassword'

def getCyclerTime (host):

    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    try:

        ssh.connect (host, username = uname, password = pwd)

        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("date")

        output = stdout.readlines()

        print ("\n The command response on the host was - ", output)

        return output [0]

    except paramiko.SSHException:

        print ("Trouble in making SSH connection")
    ssh.close()

#Get the Cycler time
timeToSet = getCyclerTime (host = HOST)

print ("\n String value of the time from Cycler - ",timeToSet)

# Convert the date string from Cycler to datetime object
laptopTimetoSet = datetime.strptime (timeToSet, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y\n')

print ("\n The converted date object is - ", laptopTimetoSet)

time = (laptopTimetoSet.year,
        laptopTimetoSet.month,
        laptopTimetoSet.isoweekday(),
        laptopTimetoSet.day,
        laptopTimetoSet.hour,
        laptopTimetoSet.minute,
        laptopTimetoSet.second,
        0,
        )

#Now set the laptop time

win32api.SetSystemTime (laptopTimetoSet.year,
                        laptopTimetoSet.month,
                        laptopTimetoSet.isoweekday(),
                        laptopTimetoSet.day,
                        laptopTimetoSet.hour,
                        laptopTimetoSet.minute,
                        laptopTimetoSet.second,
                        (laptopTimetoSet.microsecond)
                        )
```

Comment: C:\Users\lilliput\Desktop\Volume Accuracy Automation>python getHostTime.py
The host laptop current date and time is -  2018-09-12 11:08:53
The command to set is  date -s '2018-09-12 11:08:53'

 The command response on the host was -  ['Wed Sep 12 18:08:54 UTC 2018\n']

 String value of the time from Cycler -  Wed Sep 12 18:08:54 UTC 2018


 The converted date object is -  2018-09-12 18:08:54
date time now is -  2018-09-12 11:08:54.204792
date time UTC is -  2018-09-12 18:08:54.205791

Comment: You're better off setting up NTP. Seriously.

Comment: the remote machine is only accessible and not under my control. Can not use NTP.

Comment: Any experts on datetime  or win32api please provide your valuable thoughts.

Comment: The fix is to add the relevant timezone offset from GMT to the hour parameter.
laptopTimetoSet.hour + 7 worked for me because I am on PST.

Wish win32Api.SetSystemTime() had time zone parameter we could pass on.